# Redirecting to web-controller and view from rest-controller is possible?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I tried to call normal web controller from rest controller is this correct approach. If wrong how can i do?

I redirected to normal web controller using RequestDispatcher because redirect keyword not working.

From the redirected webcontroller i need to call a view . Is it possible?
If possible how? I tried sendredirect,redirect,modelAndView all not working

While performing this operations modelview and redirect is not working
sendredirect is not working

Requestdispatcher is alone working for redirection to controller form rest method.

**Apart form RequestDispatcher is ther any other way to reach webcontroller**

For redirecting to UI page redirect:,RequestDispatcher,sendreidrect() nothing works

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/test", Meethod=RequestMethod.Post)
public void callWebCont(@RequestBody String myVAl,HttpServeletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp)
{
....
....
RequestDispatcher rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("/normalController");
rd.forward(req,res);

}


@RequestMapping(value="normalController", Meethod=RequestMethod.Post)
public void callWebCont(HttpServeletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp)
{
....
....
RequestDispatcher rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("myview.jsp");
rd.forward(req,res);

}
```

My approach is correct?
If wrong how can i achieve?
While redirecting to view i am not getting any error everything goes blank.
**Why i am not getting any error or any warnings in browser and console if its wrong approach**

Comment: You cannot, it doesn't make sense to redirect to a view from a REST endpoint.

Comment: @M.Deinum i am redirecting to web controller from there i am moving to view its also not possible and bad approach? Why redirection to controller is possible but view is failing? Please help me to understand the flow

Comment: It doesn’t make Sebas. Someone sends json and suddenly gets HTML as a response. How should a client handle this?